# Zakat on wife who's husband doesn't bear expenses of wife and their child

Tags: fiqh, zakat, children, wife

I'm mother of 1 toddler child. My husband and I live separately (not divorced) and we do not have any communication between us. My husband is not interested to continue this relationship for a long time, forced us to leave his house and do not bear any kind of expenses of us - my child and I since then (almost 1.5 years), he also didn't pay the Mohrana of our wedding. I with my child live with my parents and my retired father bear the expenses of us. I sometimes bear the expenses of my child also. 
My question is since I'm taking the responsibility of my child and also not earning, is there any provision of zakat in such condition? Or, I need to pay 2.5% zakat on all my possessions- cash or savings in bank, gold etc.? Thanks.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: For savings to be eligible for zakat the list of issues you make is irrelevant what is relevant is do you have money beyond the nisab which has been in your possession for one lunar year. If so you have to pay Zakat else not. As for your other issues if you live in a Muslim country you should go to a shari'a court and complain against your ex husband as he must pay for his offspring and he must pay his mahr as marriage has been consummated.